# CMake - check if CMakeLists.txt in subdirectory is successfully built

Tags: build, cmake

Let's say I have a simple project like this:

```
main
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- sub1
|------ CMakeLists.txt
|------ sub1.cpp
|------ sub1.h
|-- sub2
|------ CMakeLists.txt
|------ sub2.cpp
|------ sub2.h
```

Then in `main/CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
add_subdirectory(sub1) # Build an executable file called exec1
add_subdirectory(sub2) # Build an executable file called exec2
add_custom_target(exec_all DEPENDS exec1 exec2)
```

Is there a way to allow `make exec_all` to run when either `exec1` or `exec2` has not been successfully built? To be clearer, I want to be able to do `make exec_all` but if, say, `make exec1` fails, it will still run and print out message saying

```
ERROR: exec1 was not successfully built. exec_all will only run exec2
```

Is this possible in the current `CMake` or is it quite a far stretch?

Comment: so far a I have tried creating a dummy `exec1` and `exec2`, but that doesn't help checking if the build is fail.

Comment: well I don't even know where I should be looking at to change this after hours of spending changing stuff here and there. I am not asking you to do my work, I am asking to be pointed toward any direction where I could look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want strict dependences, then you needn't to use `DEPENDS` option. Just create a script which performs needed actions and pass it via `COMMAND` option:

**run.sh**:

```
# Usage: run.sh target [target ...]

for target in $@; do
    if make ${target}; then
        bin/${target} # Expect executables under bin/ directory.
    else
        echo "ERROR: ${target} was not succeffully built. Do not run it"
    fi
done
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY bin) # Executables will be generated under bin/
add_subdirectory(sub1) # Build an executable file called exec1
add_subdirectory(sub2) # Build an executable file called exec2

add_custom_target(exec_all
    COMMAND /bin/sh -c ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/run.sh exec1 exec2
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Comment: this looks like the best I can find! Thanks!